# How to create a centralized provider of Expression<Func<T, object>> with different types?

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, asp.net-core, expression

I wrote sorting logic for ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application. My concept is to define a dictionary holding sort order rules. The dictionary has `string` keys. Every rule  is associated to entity type. Also there is a possibility of retrieving a sort order rule for a particular type of entity by a `string` key.

The sorting logic I wrote **does not order** any collection, it only stores and  provides information required for sorting. Every sort order rule has:

- an `Expression<Func<T, object>>`;
- a `bool` flag describing sorting way (ascending/descending);
- a `bool` flag indicating whether particular sort order rule is a default one.

I defined that data in `ISortOrderRule<T>` interface:

```cs
public interface ISortOrderRule<T>
{
    Expression<Func<T, object>> Expression { get; }
    bool IsDescending { get; }
    bool IsDefault { get; }
}
```

with default implementation in `SortOrderRule<T>` class:

```cs
public class SortOrderRule<T> : ISortOrderRule<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> Expression { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public bool IsDescending { get; set; }
}
```

The expression can be used for example as argument for [`OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby) LINQ method. `IsDefault` flag can be used in fallback mechanism to default sort order if no other was found.

Now, in order to create sort order rules for particular entity I created a generic interface `ISortOrderCollection<T>` where sort order rules can be stored in an underlaying dictionary:

```cs
public interface ISortOrderCollection<T> :
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, ISortOrderRule<T>>,
    IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<string, ISortOrderRule<T>>>,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ISortOrderRule<T>>>,
    IEnumerable
{

}
```

Readonly because I wanted it to be closed for outside world but open to classes deriving from `SortOrderCollectionBase<T>`:

```cs
public abstract class SortOrderCollectionBase<T> : ISortOrderCollection<T>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, ISortOrderRule<T>> _rules;

    public SortOrderCollectionBase()
    {
        _rules = new Dictionary<string, ISortOrderRule<T>>();
    }

    protected void AddSortOrderRule(string key, ISortOrderRule<T> sortOrderRule)
    {
        // Tweak over the key, add prefix or suffix depending on sorting way
        // So sort order rules for the same property but with opposite
        // sorting way can be distinguished.
        var sortRuleKey = BuildSortOrderRuleKey(key, sortOrderRule);

        _rules.Add(sortRuleKey, sortOrderRule);
    }

    // Implementations of interface members removed for brevity.
}
```

Now I can add some sort order rules for `Level` entity:

```cs
public class LevelSortOrderCollection : SortOrderCollectionBase<Level>
{
    public LevelSortOrderCollection()
    {
        AddSortOrderRule(nameof(Level.Position), new SortOrderRule<Level>
        {
            Expression = (level) => level.Position,
            IsDefault = true,
        });
        AddSortOrderRule(nameof(Level.Position), new SortOrderRule<Level>
        {
            Expression = (level) => level.Position,
            IsDescending = true,
        });
    }
}
```

Level model:

```cs
public class Level
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

Types implementing `ISortOrderCollection<T>` are registered in `Startup` in `ConfigureServices()` method:

```cs
services.AddScoped<ISortOrderCollection<Level>, LevelSortOrderCollection>();
// ...
```

And finally I can use the sort order collection in a controller:

```cs
public class LevelsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<Level> _levelsRepository;
    private readonly ISortOrderCollection<Level> _levelSortOrder;

    public LevelsController(
        IRepository<Level> levelsRepository,
        ISortOrderCollection<Level> levelSortOrder)
    {
        _levelsRepository = levelsRepository;
        _levelSortOrder = levelSortOrder;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sort)
    {
        var sortOrder = _levelSortOrder[sort];
        var result = await _levelsRepository.GetPageAsync(sortOrder.Expression);

        return View(result);
    }
}
```

`GetPageAsync()` of `IRepository<Level>` accepts an expression which later is used to order records with [`OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby).

Note, that I deliberately cut out some code IMO not bringing anything worth putting here like null checks, validation, controller/repository logic choosing whether to call `OrderBy()` or `OrderByDescending()` and fallbacking to default sort order. If you feel that you need to see more, let me know in comments.

## Question

How to create a centralized sort order rule provider with access to many sort order collections for multiple entities? Instead of directly injecting a sort order collection for a particular entity type inside a controller, I'd like to be able to inject a general use sort order provider, like this:

```cs
private readonly IRepository<Level> _levelsRepository;
private readonly ISortOrderProvider _sortOrderProvider;

public LevelsController(
    IRepository<Level> levelsRepository,
    ISortOrderProvider sortOrderProvider)
{
    _levelsRepository = levelsRepository;
    _sortOrderProvider = sortOrderProvider;
}
```

and then I'd call some kind of method with type parameter:

```cs
var sortOrder = _provider.GetSortOrderRule<Level>("Position");
```

which would try to find sort order rule for type of entity passed in a type parameter with a matching `string` key.

#### Final note

I'm aware all this is pretty complex, so there is a good chance to have a completely different way to achieve what I'm trying to do. I'm not closed-minded to that kind of answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend you not to implement all these dictionary interface in your `ISortOrderCollection<T>`. While it may make sense to you to make that collection an *actual* collection, there isn’t actually a lot benefit for that: After all, you mostly add items or retrieve items by their key. You don’t actually need all the other things that these interfaces will require you to implement. Instead, use a small interface that only covers what you actually need and use composition to implement this. This also makes it easier to test.

So you are saying that you want a single provider that keeps all sort order expressions for all your types. Start by thinking how you would want to use that, and build an interface that offers the necessary APIs:

```
public interface ISortOrderProvider
{
    void Add<T>(string name, ISortOrderRule<T> sortOrderRule);

    ISortOrderRule<T> Get<T>(string name);

    ISortOrderRule<T> GetDefault<T>();
}
```

Okay, so if you look at that, you will notice that you effectively have two keys now: The sort order key *and the type*. So use both as a key in a dictionary.

Now, for the default rule, there are a few strategies: You could have a separate dictionary that just stores the default rule for each type; you could also iterate through all rules, looking for the default, when you request it; or you could store the default rule under a common name that makes it possible to look up that directly. I’ll opt for the latter idea.

So here is a straightforward example implementation:

```
public class SortOrderProvider : ISortOrderProvider
{
    private const string DefaultKey = "__default";
    private readonly Dictionary<(Type, string), object> _rules = new Dictionary<(System.Type, string), object>();

    public void Add<T>(string name, ISortOrderRule<T> sortOrderRule)
    {
        _rules[(typeof(T), name)] = sortOrderRule;

        if (sortOrderRule.IsDefault)
            _rules[(typeof(T), DefaultKey)] = sortOrderRule;
    }

    public ISortOrderRule<T> Get<T>(string name)
    {
        if (_rules.TryGetValue((typeof(T), name), out var value))
            return (ISortOrderRule<T>)value;
        return GetDefault<T>();
    }

    public ISortOrderRule<T> GetDefault<T>()
    {
        if (_rules.TryGetValue((typeof(T), DefaultKey), out var value))
            return (ISortOrderRule<T>)value;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: A tuple key, that's just genius. Thank you very much! I couldn't get my head around that by myself.